# Jenkins get user who aborted a build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to get the username when a build is aborted by a user?
Preferably using jenkins pipeline code.

When a build is aborted by a user, it logs:

```
Aborted by <username>
```

so I hope it is stored as a variable for a brief period.

Use case: username to be later used to inform the user itself or other users via email or other means of messaging.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that a InterruptedBuildAction object is inserted in to the list of build action if a job is aborted. This object can be used to retrieve the user that aborted the build. I use the following function in my Jenkinsfile:

```
@NonCPS
def getAbortUser()
{
    def causee = ''
    def actions = currentBuild.getRawBuild().getActions(jenkins.model.InterruptedBuildAction)
    for (action in actions) {
        def causes = action.getCauses()

        // on cancellation, report who cancelled the build
        for (cause in causes) {
            causee = cause.getUser().getDisplayName()
            cause = null
        }
        causes = null
        action = null
    }
    actions = null

    return causee
}
```

Comment: `getRawBuild()` is apparently impossible to use now, have you found an alternative for this?

Answer (score 4):

In fact you can have this information with the REST API, just use the following URL with an appropriate build:

```
/api/json?tree=actions[causes[*]]&pretty=true
```

And you should be able to find the requested information under actions[causes], e.g.:

```
{
    "_class" : "jenkins.model.InterruptedBuildAction",
    "causes" : [
        {
          "_class" : "jenkins.model.CauseOfInterruption$UserInterruption",
          "shortDescription" : "Aborted by some_user_name"
        }
      ]
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there seem to be no other solutions at the moment but to tweak Jenkin's code itself and a workaround.

***Post-Build actions*** → ***Editable Email Notification*** → *Triggers* → ***Add Trigger*** → ***Aborted*** → *Send To* → ***Add*** → ***Requestor*** → [image] → ... *[Jenkins Mailer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)*:

> Sends email to the user who initiated the build.

There's no **Aborter** to add.

`http://<jenkins>/job/<project name>/lastBuild/api/xml` shows:

```
...
<result>ABORTED</result>
...
```

but there's no info who aborted the build either.

A workaround could be to `curl http://<jenkins>/job/<project name>/<build #>` in a [Post build task](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) script and to `grep` for `<p>Aborted by user username</p>`.

Comment: `curl` the console log is the only (good) method. Thank you @Gerold Broser for the idea.

Comment: Not what I would have chosen but it works. You dont need to use the suggested plugin in this answer I got it working inside a `post` block on my pipeline